# how to keep Bluetooth speaker connected to raspberry pi does not sleep

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, alsa, bluez, raspberry-pi-zero

I am developing software for playing audio on bluetooth speaker, so far, it works with raspberry pi 0 w, using blue-alsa, but the problem is that after a while the speaker gets into sleep mode and then i need to wake it up again manually.

is there a way to avoid speaker getting to sleep mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to this issue as following feature

in bluealsa there is a [keep-alive](https://github.com/Arkq/bluez-alsa/issues/171)